# Allow to select SAML sign-on method for existing Azure enterprise application

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml, saml-2.0

When creating an Azure enterprise application, the Azure portal provides different options (templates) on how to create the app.
[image: Azure enterprise application creation dialog]

## A

I had created an enterprise application **A** using the ***Register an application to integrate with Azure AD (App you're developing)*** option.

Now need to change **A**'s the *Single sign-on method* to *SAML*. But when selecting

- Enterprise Applications > A > Manage: Single sign-on

I am not presented the choice to select SAML:
[image]

## B

Out of curiosity, I created another enterprise app **B**, this time using the ***Integrate any other application you don't find in the gallery (Non-gallery)*** option.

For **B**, it is possible to select SAML as the *single sign-on method*:
[image]

## Question

What do I have to do to enable/allow SAML as the single-sign-on method for **A**?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created an **Azure Enterprise Application** (**TestA**) by selecting *"Register an application to integrate with Azure AD (App you're developing)"* option:

[image]

Now, I created another **Azure Enterprise Application** (**TestB**) by selecting *"Integrate any other application you don't find in the gallery (Non-gallery)"* option:

[image]

In the **TestB** Application SAML option is available to configure SSO like below:

[image]

Whereas, in **TestA** SAML option isn't available to configure SAML SSO like below:

[image]

> **Note** that: Configuring the SAML SSO depends and varies on the Application you create.

When you create an application by selecting ***Register an application to integrate with Azure AD (App you're developing)*** option integrates with AD and allows to use OIDC standard for SSO.

- These kind of applications doesn't support to configure SSO with SAML.
- It uses OpenID Connect and OAuth and so most SSO configuration will already be completed.

> What do I have to do to enable/allow SAML as the single-sign-on method for **A**?

For the Applications configured by selecting **"*Register an application to integrate with Azure AD (App you're developing)*"** option by default it configures OpenID Connect and OAuth and it cannot be configured to use SAML SSO.

- There are many applications integrated with Azure AD (In Gallery/ not in Gallery) and few applications doesn't support SAML SSO e.g. smartSheet.

**Hence**, as a workaround if you want to create your own Application and configure SAML SSO you have to choose *"Integrate any other application you don't find in the gallery (Non-gallery)"* only.

Otherwise, you can choose **Gallery Application** like below:

[image]

**Reference:**

[How do I configure Azure AD SSO with SAML for a non-gallery application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1159963/how-do-i-configure-azure-ad-sso-with-saml-for-a-no) by Shweta Mathur.